# C++ Fast Percentile Calculation

Tags: c++, vector, percentile

I'm trying to write a percentile function that takes 2 vectors as input and 1 vector as output. One of the input vector (Distr) would be a distribution of random numbers. The other input vector (Tests) would be a vector of values that I want to calculate the percentile from Distr. The output would be a vector (same size as Tests) that returns the percentile for each value in Tests.

The following is an example of what I want:

```
Input Distr = {3, 5, 8, 12}
Input Tests = {4, 9}
Output Percentile = {0.375, 0.8125}
```

Following is my implementation in C++:

```
vector<double> Percentile(vector<double> Distr, vector<double> Tests)
{
    double prevValue, nextValue;
    vector<double> result;
    unsigned distrSize = Distr.size();

    std::sort(Distr.begin(), Distr.end());

    for (vector<double>::iterator test = Tests.begin(); test != Tests.end(); test++)
    {

        if (*test <= Distr.front())
        {
            result.push_back((double) 1 / distrSize); // min percentile returned (not important)
        }
        else if (Distr.back() <= *test)
        {
            result.push_back(1); // max percentile returned (not important)
        }
        else
        {
            prevValue = Distr[0];
            for (unsigned sortedDistrIdx = 1; sortedDistrIdx < distrSize; sortedDistrIdx++)
            {
                nextValue = Distr[sortedDistrIdx];

                if (nextValue <= *test)
                {
                    prevValue = nextValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    // linear interpolation
                    result.push_back(((*test - prevValue) / (nextValue - prevValue) + sortedDistrIdx) / distrSize);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The size of both Distr and Tests can be from 2,000 to 30,000.

Are there any existing libraries that can calculate percentile as shown above (or similar)? If not how can I make the above code faster?

Comment: It would help if instead of using `push_back` you would preallocate the vectors involved.

Comment: One way is to take your input parameters by reference. At the moment big vectors are being copied for no reason.

Comment: @JonathanPotter since Distr is sorted, taking it by reference would modify the input.  Also, when both are large, the linear cost of copying is a trivial fraction of the total time.

Comment: You say that `Distr` *would be a distribution of random numbers*, yet in your example it is sorted, and most answers *assume* that `Distr` is sorted. Please clarify whether `Distr` is initially sorted. From your code, it appears that it is not sorted, since you first sort it. Note that this sort may well be the dominant contributor to the overall costs.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know whether `test` can be assumed sorted initialy or not.

Comment: you can write your algorithm as an opencl kernel and then you can take advantage of the power of any GPU that supports opencl.

Comment: `(double) 1` is unnecessary. Just use `1.0`. *Are there any existing libraries that can calculate percentile as shown above (or similar)?* this is off-topic. Try [softwarerecs.se]. *If not how can I make the above code faster?* try [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
vector<double> Percentile(vector<double> Distr, vector<double> Tests)
{
    double prevValue, nextValue;
    vector<double> result;
    unsigned distrSize = Distr.size();

    std::sort(Distr.begin(), Distr.end());

    for (vector<double>::iterator test = Tests.begin(); test != Tests.end(); test++)
    {
        if (*test <= Distr.front())
        {
            result.push_back((double) 1 / distrSize); // min percentile returned (not important)
        }
        else if (Distr.back() <= *test)
        {
            result.push_back(1); // max percentile returned (not important)
        }
        else
        {
            auto it = lower_bound(Distr.begin(), Distr.end(), *test);
            prevValue = *(it - 1);
            nextValue = *(it + 1);
            // linear interpolation
            result.push_back(((*test - prevValue) / (nextValue - prevValue) + (it - Distr.begin())) / distrSize);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that instead of making a linear search on *Distr* for each test, I leverage the fact that *Distr* is sorted and make a binary search instead (using *lower_bound*).

Answer (score 0):

The linear search of Distr for each element of Tests would be the major amount of time if both of those are large.

When Distr is much larger, it is much faster to do a binary search instead of linear.  There is a binary search algorithm available in std.  You don't need to write one.

When Tests is nearly as big as Distr, or bigger, it is faster to do an index sort of Tests and then sequence through the two sorted lists together storing the results, then output the stored results in a next pass.

Edit:  I see the answer by Csaba Balint gives a little more detail on what I meant by "sequence through the two sorted lists together".

Edit:  The basic methods being discussed are:
1) Sort both lists and then process linearly together, time NlogN+MlogM
2) Sort just one list and binary search, time (N+M)logM
3) Sort just the other list and partition, time I haven't figured out, but in the case of N and M similar, it has to be larger than either method 1 or 2, and in the case of N sufficiently tiny has to be smaller than methods 1 or 2.

Comment: `bool std::binary_search(first, last, value)` returns if an element equal to `value` is found within the specified range -- how is the possibly helpful here? In the example, the test 4 was not contained within the input distribution.

Comment: @Walter I didn't say **which** "binary search" method in std I meant (because I was too lazy to look up details).  There is one.  I expect it is `lower_bound`.  If I had meant `binary_search` rather than "binary search" I would have said that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a linear algorithm for your problem (linear times logarithmic in both sizes). You need to sort both vectors, and then have two iterators going through each (`itDistr`, `itTest`). There are three possibilities:

1.
    *itDistr < *itTest

Here, you have nothing to except increment `itDistr`.

2.
    *itDistr >= *itTest

This is the case when you found a test case where *`itTest` is element of the interval `[ *(itDistr-1), *itDistr )`. So you have to do the interpolation you have used (linear), and then increment `itTest`.

The third possibility is where any of then reaches the end of its container vector. You also have to define what happens in the beginning and at the and, it depends on how you define the distribution from the series of your numbers.

> Are there any existing libraries that can calculate percentile as shown above (or similar)?

Probably, but it is easy to implement it, and you can have fine control over the interpolation technique.

Comment: Your method is clearly sub-optimal, since full sort of the input (random) distribution is not necessary.

Comment: @Walter, for the case when both input vectors are very large (especially if similar in size), propose a better method before saying the method in this answer is sub-optimal.

Comment: @JSF, thanks :) I cannot (yet) comment to your answer, but I think you meant std::lover_bound() (or upper_bound).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is relevant to the case that `input` is initially random (not sorted) and `test.size()` smaller than `input.size()`, which is the most common situation.

Suppose there is only one test value. Then you only have to partition the `input` with respect to this value *and* obtain the upper(lower) bound of the lower(upper) parition to compute the respective percentile. This is much faster than a full sort on input (which quicksort implements as a recursion of partitions).

If `test.size()>1`, then you first sort `test` (ideally, `test` is already sorted and you can skip this step) and subsequently proceed with the test elements in increasing order, each time only partitioning the upper part from the previous partition. Since we also keep track of the lower bound of the upper partition (as well as the upper bound of the lower partition), we can detect if no input data are between consecutive test elements, and avoid to partition.

This algorithm should be near-optimal, since no unnecessary information is generated (as it would be with a full sort of `input`).

If subsequent partitioning splits the input roughly in half, the algorithm would be optimal. This could be approximated by proceeding not in increasing order of `test`, but by subsequent halving of `test`, i.e. starting with the median test element, then the first & third quartile, etc..

Comment: At some relative size of the two inputs, you are correct.  When `test` is the size of the log of `input` I believe you would have already outgrown your method.  At some even smaller size of `test` (relative to `input`) you are correct.

Comment: @JSF if `input` is initially random (as specified in the OP), then I cannot see how you can obtain a faster method.

Comment: If there is no input data between consecutive tests elements, how could you detect the fact that no work is needed?  Instead you would be doing that unneeded work.  Now that you changed to sorting `test` you should partition `input` recursively on halves of `test` rather than linearly.  For random correlation between the two, that would improve your method a lot.  It still breaks down as the two sizes become similar.

Comment: @JSF You're presumably correct. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I realized there is a further improvement to your method, assuming both lists initially random:  A recursive functions starting with both inputs random and sorting neither:  Take the first element of `Tests` and partition **both** inputs on that value.  That gives you the answer for the first element.  Then recursively pass the first partition of `Tests` with only the first partition of `Distr` (and separately second with second).  Random input should take (N+M)logN

Comment: @JSF algorithms are just fun!